# Airflow eternal worker loop

Tags: python, airflow

I have an instance of airflow working with CeleryExecutor, which is working fine, but airflow constantly restarts a worker that does nothing, i dont really know what to do or how to fix this

Logs:

```
[2021-02-03 19:55:58,151] {{__init__.py:50}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor

[2021-02-03 19:55:58,151] {{dagbag.py:417}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/pod_generator.py:39: DeprecationWarning: This module is deprecated. Please use `airflow.kubernetes.pod`.

  from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.pod import _extract_volume_mounts

[2021-02-03 19:56:02,560] {{security.py:477}} INFO - Start syncing user roles.

[2021-02-03 19:56:04,307] {{security.py:387}} INFO - Fetching a set of all permission, view_menu from FAB meta-table

[2021-02-03 19:56:05,849] {{security.py:330}} INFO - Cleaning faulty perms

[2021-02-03 19:56:07 +0000] [253] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou

[2021-02-03 19:56:07 +0000] [32641] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32641)

[2021-02-03 19:56:21 +0000] [253] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin

[2021-02-03 19:56:21 +0000] [710] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 710

[2021-02-03 19:56:26,072] {{__init__.py:50}} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor

[2021-02-03 19:56:26,080] {{dagbag.py:417}} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /usr/local/airflow/dags

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/kubernetes/pod_generator.py:39: DeprecationWarning: This module is deprecated. Please use `airflow.kubernetes.pod`.

  from airflow.contrib.kubernetes.pod import _extract_volume_mounts

[2021-02-03 19:56:30,414] {{security.py:477}} INFO - Start syncing user roles.

[2021-02-03 19:56:31,060] {{security.py:387}} INFO - Fetching a set of all permission, view_menu from FAB meta-table

[2021-02-03 19:56:31,928] {{security.py:330}} INFO - Cleaning faulty perms

[2021-02-03 19:56:32 +0000] [253] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou

[2021-02-03 19:56:32 +0000] [32748] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32748)

[2021-02-03 19:56:51 +0000] [253] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin

[2021-02-03 19:56:51 +0000] [815] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 815
```

as you can see, is the same job everytime, nonstop, this happens contantly in the machine with airflow

Inside the machine, the process appear as follows:

```
airflow   2334 11.1  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z    20:03   0:00 [airflow schedul] <defunct>
airflow   2338 13.8  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z    20:03   0:00 [airflow schedul] <defunct>
```